# Asynchronously execute subprocesses in perl and capture their output

Tags: multithreading, perl, concurrency

I need to asynchronously run two commands in a Perl script and then process their outputs after both of the commands have finished executing.

So far I've tried using the threads package with the IPC::Run3 package. But this doesnt' work. This example doesn't produce any output:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use threads;
use IPC::Run3;

my $out1 = "";

my $t1 = async {
    run3([qw(echo foo)], \undef, \$out1, \undef);
};

my $out2 = "";

my $t2 = async {
    run3([qw(echo bar)], \undef, \$out2, \undef);
};

my $out3 = "";
run3([qw(echo bar)], \undef, \$out3, \undef);

$t1->join();
$t2->join();


print("$out1\n");
print("$out2\n");
print("$out3\n");
```

Comment: First of all, you'll need to make `$out1` and `$out2` shared (or return the value from the thread and receive it using `join`). But it still doesn't work. IPC::Run3 doesn't appear to be thread-safe. It seems to work if you load IPC::Run3 in each of the thread instead of before-hand, but I don't know if that's a reliable solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IPC::Run3 appears to have issues with threads, but that doesn't appear to the case for the more capable IPC::Run.

```perl
use threads;
use threads::shared;

use IPC::Run qw( run );

my $out1 :shared = "";
my $t1 = async {
    run( [qw( echo foo )], ">", \$out1 );
};

my $out2 :shared = "";
my $t2 = async {
    run( [qw( echo bar )], ">", \$out2 );
};

my $out3;
run( [qw( echo baz )], ">", \$out3 );

$t1->join();
$t2->join();
```

Don't forget to make your shared variable shared.

Atlernative:

```perl
use threads;

use IPC::Run qw( run );

my $t1 = async {
    my $out = "";
    run( [qw( echo foo )], ">", \$out );
    $out
};

my $t2 = async {
    my $out = "";
    run( [qw( echo bar )], ">", \$out );
    $out
};

my $out3 = do {
   my $out = "";
   run( [qw( echo baz )], ">", \$out );
   $out
};

my $out1 = $t1->join();
my $out2 = $t2->join();
```